# Delete values from db2 table if exist in schema in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

i want to ask for a little help about my problem. I have sql query that get all the tables from some schema and put those tables in a list in Python. For example:

```
tablesList = ['TABLE1','TABLE2',...]
```

After i get this list of tables that i want i go one more time through each table in a for loop for example:

```
for t in range(len(tables)):
       table = tables[t]
       ...
       #here i want to check if this table exist in some db2 schema and if exist delete content  
       #of this table, otherwise go with next table check and don't delete content
```

Query for checking will be:

```
sql = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES 
             WHERE TYPE = 'T' 
             AND CREATOR = 'MY_SCHEMA' 
             AND NAME = '{table}';""".format(table = table)

cursor.execute(sql)
rows_count = cursor.fetchone()
if rows_count is None:
    pass
else:
    delete...
```

Comment: isn't below query helped.
```sql = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES 
         WHERE TYPE = 'T' 
         AND NAME = '{table}';""".format(table = table)
```
above list entries of your table in all the schema's. When your input schema doesn't match. you can go for delete content. I don't see a big challenge. Can you elaborate on the issue where you are facing.

Comment: Why not directly try to delete content, the fact that the table exists when you check in systables doesn't implie it still does when you try to clear it, and it does not implie you can delete content (no authority, FK prevents deletion, concurent access, etc...) . If it raises an exception where SQLSTATE=42704/SQLCODE=-204 then it does not exist

Comment: Why i don' delete the content directly? I don' know if the table exist in the scheme  from which i want to deleted. I get table list from other source scheme and i want to check if the same tables exist in the target scheme then to delete the content

Comment: What I say is just try to delete the content, if you have no error then the table exists and is now empty, else you have an error you can can choose to ignore or not based on SQLSTATE or SQLCODE, maybe it's not perfect but if you check with SYSTABLES and have you're process running twice in paralel, then you have possibliy one process where SYSTABLES says yes and TRUNCATE TABLE says table does not exist